# mysql update where if else cant get it prioritize

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I want that, if there is a Premium account set one Premium account to inuse=1, if there is no premium account then update any else account.

But this does not prioritize Premium accounts, as it just updates the first entry in my db row.
How to use this with if else / case. I couldnt find any if / else / case thread where its used in the WHERE part of the sql query

```
UPDATE accounts SET inuse = 1 WHERE accstatus = 'PREMIUM' AND inuse = 0 AND banned = 0
                                 OR inuse = 0 AND banned = 0 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ORDER BY` clause in the `UPDATE` statement that prioritizes any row with `accstatus` set to `'PREMIUM'`:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET inuse = 1 
WHERE inuse = 0 AND banned = 0
ORDER BY accstatus = 'PREMIUM' DESC                                 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: wow thank you. So easy workaround and I wasn't thinking about it!
So btw... there is no way to have if/else or case in a WHERE statement?

Comment: @HumanKhoo you can use the IF() function or a CASE expression, but this does not do what you have in mind. The WHERE clause filters the table. It does not set priority of any kind to the rows returned.